# What would be a good algorithm for patching binary files on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, memory, embedded-linux, patch

I am trying to reduce data transfer to my embedded Linux device by creating patches for almost similar binaries.

I have memory constraints on my device and hence heavy algorithms like bsdiff and bspatch are unaffordable on my target for binary sizes of around 36-60 MB. I would like to know the commands that have the best algorithms for diffing and patching files that can work with minimalistic amount of memory. I am attaching output of *[df](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_(Unix))* and [free](https://linux.die.net/man/1/free) as well here.

[image: Memory details of target]

Comment: You need to specify exactly what constraints you have (as in, amount of memory), because most people don't consider `bsdiff` or `xdelta` to be unusual tools for this purpose.

Comment: I am unable to use bspatch for a 35 mb file. bsdiff i guess would take even more memory approx 17 times of filesize. So I am looking for a cheaper algorithm even if it takes a lot of time to patch.

Comment: How about offloading the patching to a $10 Raspberry Pi Zero W with 512MB of RAM?

Comment: Its a legacy device and hardware changes are not possible. Hence I am looking for an algorithm that can work within the constraints.

Comment: @bk2204 the issue is not that the binaries are not present. The issue is what algorithm works with minimal memory under linux. Rdiff could also be a solution but I am not aware if it takes too much memory as well. Bsdiff details are at this link it consumes huge memory and maybe a misfit for embedded world. http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/

Comment: If you were talking to me, I wasn't proposing a hardware change. I was proposing sending data over wifi or Ethernet to a Raspberry Pi for patching.

Comment: @Mark..The patching needs to be done on the target finally  as it can only communicate to the backhaul. It is a secure smart grid  router repeater so raspberry pie can not be used with it. The bspatch is unable to apply delta due to memory constraints as shown in the pic. So I was wondering if someone has split the binary and created patches to be reassembled on destination.

Comment: Please review *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* and *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65543220/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that rdiff uses a slightly better algorithm in terms of memory, but it creates a bigger patch (delta) file than either of bsdiff or xdelta3.

xdelta3 creates the smallest patchfile, but it uses more memory to create the patch than rdiff does. So in terms of the created patch size, we have—*xdelta3* < *bsdiff* < *rdiff*.

And in terms of memory consumption while applying patch we have—rdiff < xdelta3 < bsdiff

Answer (score 1):

For comparison between *xdelta* and *bsdiff*, the bsdiff (mbsdiff) seems to be more efficient in terms of delta size and memory consumption.